# Python, Requests, BS4: Submitting a button with no name

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Essentially, I have an html form. I can post everything I need, but because the button has no name, I cannot pass "Login" to it. However, I can find the button using BS.find_all. Is there a way I can feed data to the button without knowing its name?

```
m["username"] = "test"
m["password"] = "password"
m[{this is were my problem is}] = "Login"
t = requests.post(URL, data=m)
```

As you can see I am getting elements from their names and filling in data. I since the button does not have a name, I cannot use it as data.

```
    submitbtn = soup.find_all("button", class_="submit button")
```

I can find the button like this.
EDIT: Answer:

```
submitbtn = soup.find_all("button", class_="submit button")
m[submitbtn] = "Login"
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question and post necessary code?

Comment: I added some code, I hope it clarifies a little bit.

Comment: Have you tried getting the element by its index in the bs4 result set of your find_all?

Comment: I am an idiot, I didn't index it because it only returned one. Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it.